# How to filter out ringing current in a local battery telephone system?

Tags: filter, telephone

We have a network of manually-switched local-battery telephones. Here is depiction of the circuit in one telephone:

[image]

```
Ü    transformer
OB   local battery (1.5 V)
GU   hook switch
F    speaker
M    microphone
Ind  magneto (30–100 V, 15–30 Hz)
W    ringer
```

We have a switchboard where we can manually connect subscribers with one-another. Since this can take a while, we would like to play hold-music while we establish a connection. Hold music is being played back by connecting the output of a sound card to the A and B leads of the telephone we'd like to play music to.

This works great unless the subscriber starts to crank the magneto. This fries the sound card. How can we construct a simple filter that protects the sound card from the ringing voltage, while letting the music through?

I thought about a simple high-pass filter, but I have no clue about how to construct one and I prefer to use a design someone more competent than me designed because frying sound cards is an expensive way of testing things.

I would prefer a solution that does not require any additional power source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply coupling the signal via a small capacitor will act as a high-pass filter, however the output waveform of a magneto is very peaky and has harmonics that could be hard to filter out without affecting the audio.

To provide complete protection you should put back-to-back Zener diodes across the signal wires wires to clamp voltage spikes, and a resistor in series to limit current. Usually a transformer is also inserted to isolate the computer's ground and provide a balanced output to the phone line.

Here's an example of a passive phone line interface (it has two identical circuits for input and output - you only need one of them).

[Computer audio interface to wire-based telephone network](http://colinfahey.com/phone_interface/phone_interface.html)
[image]

Comment: This sounds like the circuit I want. Let me test that!